# publish_actions permission error

Tags: android, permissions, facebook-login

I'm having a problem with publish_actions. I added publish_actions to Items, but got the error shown below:

```
It looks like you haven't made any API requests to access content 
with the publish_actions permission in the last 30 days.
```

Please let me know how to fix this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you in a situation of asking for the new "login review"?  If so, I **suspect** (not sure) that Facebook checks that you, as the admin of the app, also **uses** the app and go through the relevant logic. I may be wrong, but see if it helps.

Comment: Thanks for reply.I had reviewed 3 days ago.Logic was not good,so I modification source.I tried submitting for Re-review, but that error is shown Facebook page.I can't submit for re-review.That error was't shown 3 days ago.If you know what should I do, please help.

Comment: This is what happened to me: In Facebook, I am the admin of app X which needs publish_action permission. X was created long ago, so it works until April 30. I tested X with several users, and then used my Facebook account to submit for review. I got this error in the notes that explain publish_action. After testing X with **my** account, I stopped getting this error.

Comment: Thank you so so so so much.I have submitted for re-review.I deeply appreciate your kindness.

Answer (score 2):

Previous answers do help. But for those who struggled like me, here's the trick:

You have to use the API to post something, but you can't just do that with any Facebook user. You have to use the APP OWNER's account. That's the Facebook user that you used to login to developers.facebook.com

None of any other accounts counts. Only that one can do it. When they say "YOU". They mean literally.

Hope this helps others with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem with me .So I have a create dummy application using facebook graph api  in which pubish_actions permission is used to post the data and when I login and post the data with another facebook id then  it shows error of denied permission then i go again and submit the items again .The error goes it self .

Comment: Thank you very much for reply.I have submitted for re-review.