# Publish Action review failed

Tags: facebook, action, oracle-sqldeveloper, publish

[image]

We are applying for App to use publish action to allow us share post in user's timeline. But when we could not submit our review because it says "It looks like you haven't made any API requests to access content with the publish_actions permission in the last 30 days."

We don't know how to fix this error.

As it shows in the picture, it say that we have not made any API requests to access content with the publish_actions permission in the last 30 days."

Could anyone be of help? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 11):

This may same issue with [publish_actions permission error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27085086/publish-actions-permission-error)
you get this issue because you did not make request with this permission before.
You can use Graph API Explorer to make post request (post with API me/feed which need two params: message, access_token) with your applications.
When you success to post feed to wall, this will be resolved.

Comment: dear, i do not know how to operate it clearly. Could be tell more in details. Thanks sooo much for your help. I really appreciate it!

Comment: - on facebook developer page, select Graph API Explorer on menu.
- on the Graph API Explorer page, select your app want to review by clicking on Graph API Explorer you will get list of your app.
- Select your app and click on get access Token, check on permissions you need. 
- change method to post and past "me/feed" to textbox
- click add a field and add two field "message", "access_token"  ("message" is your message and "access_token" is token on textbox access_token)

Comment: I really appreciate for your help. I did as the steps you said above, but when I click "Submit" button, the error occurs, as you can see in the screenshot.

Could you tell what should I do next? Thanks sooo much for your help!!![enter image description here][1]

[1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/heGws.png error screenshot

Comment: - First you need get token that have publish_actions by click on button "Get Access Token", you can see this permission in tab "Extend Permissions".
- value for params message  is what you want to post
- value for access_token is text on text box Access Token.
Hope this helpful for you.

Answer (score 6):

Here's the trick: You have to use the API to post something, but you can't just do that with any Facebook user. You have to use the **APP OWNER**'s account. That's the Facebook user that you used to login to developers.facebook.com

None of any other accounts counts. Only that one can do it.

When they say "YOU". They mean literally.

Hope this helps others with the same problem.